# Request from one docker container to another fails

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've been trying to connect two docker containers. My flask backend and my react frontend, when I use localhost in the request the request goes through, but when i use the docker container name ie http://backend-service:5000/endpoint , the name can't be resolved. The documentation states that the containers connect to the same networking automatically and that accessing services from one should be as simple as that. I've tried adding links to the docker compose file as well with no luck.

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  backend-service:
    build: ./api
    expose:
      - 5000
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ./api:/usr/src/app
    environment:
      - FLASK_ENV=development
      - FLASK_APP=app.py
      - FLASK_DEBUG=1
  client-service:
    build: ./clientside
    expose: 
      - 3000
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./clientside/src:/usr/src/app/src
      - ./clientside/public:/usr/src/app/public
    links:
      - "backend-service:backend"
```

Comment: I think `links` is redundant. Within the docker-compose network, `client-service` can reference `backend-service` using `backend-service` as the hostname. Since `backend-service` exposes `5000`, *within* docker-compose, `client-service` calls to `backend-service:5000` should succeed (assuming your Flask app is listening on `5000`). The ports are exposed on the host (`3000` and `5000`) and can be referenced as `localhost:3000`, `localhost:5000`. Aside from debugging, it's likely that you shouldn't `ports: - "5000:5000"`  as your backend should be exposed only through `client-service` calls.

Comment: You say it's a React frontend; is the actual HTTP request being launched out of code running in a browser?  That has no visibility into Docker land at all and needs to use the host's DNS name and the published port of the backend.